# jQuery & Ajax page loader on a php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, soap

How can i set a jQuery/AJAX page loader on a php page.

My php page is using a SOAP connection. All the request sent to the results page are coming from a search form and direct links with params.

At this time i have a loader that is call with the below codes

```
<!-- Javascript Page Loader -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pace.min.js" data-pace-options='{ "ajax": false }'></script>

// pace.js should be active

if (typeof Pace != "undefined") {
    var soapPageLoadingContent = false;
    //document.write('<img alt="" src="images/logo2.png" style="display: none;">');
    var logoImg = new Image();
    logoImg.src = "images/logo2.png";
    var soapPageLoadingProgressInterval = setInterval(function() {
        try {
            if (document.body.className.indexOf("pace-done") != -1) {
                clearInterval(soapPageLoadingProgressInterval);
            }
            if (document.body.className.indexOf("pace-running") == -1) {
                return;
            }
            if (!soapPageLoadingContent) {
                document.getElementsByClassName("pace-activity")[0].innerHTML = '<div class="loading-page style3">' +
        '<div class="loading-page-wrapper">' +
            '<div class="container">' +
                '<div class="loading-page-content table-wrapper full-width">' +
                    '<div class="table-cell" style="vertical-align: middle;">' +
                        '<h1 class="logo block">' +
                            '<a href="index.html" title="bookingAssist">' +
                                '<img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Your personal assistant" />' +
                            '</a>' +
                        '</h1>' +
                        '<div class="loading-text block">Se incarca...</div>' +
                        '<div class="loading-progress-bar block col-sms-10 col-sm-8 col-md-6">' +
                            '<div class="loading-progress" style="width: 69%;"></div>' +
                            '<div class="loading-percent"></div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<img src="images/pages/loading/girl.png" alt="" class="bottom-image animated" data-animation-type="fadeInUp" data-animation-duration="3">' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

                soapPageLoadingContent = true;
            }

            var percent = document.getElementsByClassName("pace-progress")[0].getAttribute("data-progress-text");
            document.getElementsByClassName("loading-progress")[0].style.width = percent;
        } catch(e) {  }
    }, 50);
```

But the loader is snown up only after the PHP SOAP client retrieve the requested data.

Is there a posibility to create a sistem to display the loader whilst the SOAP client retrives the data ?